# How to use custom font in outlook Emails

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, webfonts, email-templates

I am using custom font in outlook email but when client receive it is not showing the exact one.

Help required

Answer (score 0):

Per [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/), `@font-face` is only supported in Outlook on macOS.

[image: Email Client support for @font-face]

Answer (score 0):

I never came across any such stuff in Outlook for Windows, as i failed to see any option from Outlook API perspective.